# PSQL query syntax error because of multistep WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, psql

I'm running a simple update query that is hitting all sorts of syntax errors and I can't figure out why.

This select runs fine:

```
SELECT quote, author
FROM inspiration
WHERE length(quote)<250
AND used IS NULL
OR used > now()::date - 365
OFFSET floor(random()*10)
LIMIT 1;
```

While this get's a syntax error:

```
UPDATE inspiration SET used=now()
WHERE length(quote)<250
AND used IS NULL
OR used > now()::date - 365
OFFSET floor(random()*10)
LIMIT 1;
```

Removing `OFFSET floor(random()*10) LIMIT 1` solves the issue. But I need one single random row updated.

Running EXPLAIN doesn't help since it's a syntax error. Wrapping both WHERE statements in parenthesis doesn't help.

Comment: @juergend I do. It was stackoverflow's recommendation. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I need one single random row updated.

If I understand you correctly you want something like:

```
UPDATE inspiration
SET used = now()
WHERE id = (SELECT id          -- PK of inspiration table
            FROM inspiration
            WHERE length(quote)<250
              AND used IS NULL
                  OR used > now()::date - 365
            ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1);
```

Also I belive that:

```
length(quote)<250
AND used IS NULL
OR used > now()::date - 365

-- should be
length(quote)<250
AND (used IS NULL
     OR used > now()::date - 365)
```

Comment: That solved it. I knew it was something simple like that, but couldn't find any worthwhile sources for it. Thank you @lad2025!